# animate bootstrap theme not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Animate.css works outsite of container and header but not inside. I spent whole day and i can't find fix and i am doing everything correct. Like i said it works if i put it randomly somewhere. Thank you in advance.

EDIT: it won't do any animation, no matter what animation i choose!

EDIT2: animation happens to fast and i cannot see it on my computer, how can i delay it? thank you!

```
 <header id="intro">
   <div class="container">
      <div class="table">
         <div class="header-text">
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                  <div class="animated bounce">
                     <h2 class="light white">text.</h2>
                     <h1 class="white typed"></h1>
                     <ol></ol>
                     <a href="#" class="btn btn-blue">sign up</a>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
         <h6 class="light white">Copyright &copy; 2016</h6>
      </div>
   </div>
</header>
```

Comment: so... the question is? ( you should reproduce you issue in a snippet in your question or a jsfiddle.net )

Comment: Please add a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example to your question.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: animate is not doing its job. Basically it wouldn't do any animation on the text..

Comment: Yes, there is no way to be animation there, because there is only html that you have. Got some javascript somewhere?

Comment: why do i need javascript, i am using animate.css theme i call animations from there ^^ please help

Comment: @CeylanMumunKocabaş, you do not need any javascript for that because it uses CSS3 animations (http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp)

Comment: my bad, you right...

Answer (score 0):

After pasting the whole animate.css into the CSS of jsfiddle, your works fine:
https://jsfiddle.net/khc7ytf3/

I just added the infinite class for better visualization.

```html
<header id="intro">
   <div class="container">
      <div class="table">
         <div class="header-text">
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                  <div class="animated bounce infinite">
                     <h2 class="light white">text.</h2>
                     <h1 class="white typed"></h1>
                     <ol></ol>
                     <a href="#" class="btn btn-blue">sign up</a>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
         <h6 class="light white">Copyright &copy; 2016</h6>
      </div>
   </div>
</header>
```

Are you sure, you added the animate.css to your html file?
(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/daneden/animate.css/master/animate.css)

Check out the readme how to use animate.css (https://github.com/daneden/animate.css/blob/master/README.md)

I assume you're testing on a browser that supports CSS3 animations?
(http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp)

Comment: I don't understand your problem then. You are saying that "Animate.css works outsite of container and header but not inside." - according to your html code it works inside the .container div and the header element. What are you expecting?

Comment: how can i add delay? :) look my answer please ^

Comment: the animation execution is specified with `-webkit-animation-duration: 1s; animation-duration: 1s;` - but it would be very helpful to get a minimal, complete, and verifiable example with all relevant code (stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as already pointed out

Comment: @swipeales, did that solve your problem and answer your question?